# Making area around radio buttons clickable in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a table of radio buttons. I'm trying to make it so that when I click the area around the radio button, the radio button should be selected.

```
            <% (1..6).each do |i| %>
                <td style="width: 8%">
                    <%= radio_button_tag(question.id, i, false, required: true) %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
```

I've tried wrapping the radio button inside a label, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What code did you use when trying to make a label? Make sure the `for` attribute is correctly populated.

Comment: And you might want to adjust the `<label>`'s `display` to make it fill the whole table cell.